# New project created with eclipse buildship is improperly configured (packages not recognised)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

I used buildship to create a fresh project, but the projects created don't seem to be recognised properly by eclipse. It seems that it doesn't recognise the existence of packages, and it just shows me the file structure. What went wrong here?

[image: picture of project layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to me having java 14 installed, and it seems my version of buildship couldn't deal with that just yet. Buildship 3.1.4 does fix this. Updating buildship should be quite easy.